# CentOS/RHEL download dependencies

Tags: dependencies, centos, odbc, rpm, rhel

How to download all dependecies (include recurcive) of local .rpm package?
I'm need to download dependencies of postgresql-odbc-16.00.0000-3.fc40.x86_64.rpm.
I didn't find it in any repository.

Command `yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package-name>` can't get depencencies of local .prm file.

Command `rpm -qp postgresql-odbc-16.00.0000-3.fc40.x86_64.rpm  --requires`
gets dependensies, but they need to be searched for downloading on various sites, I would like to have an automatic solution.

P.S. I'm need to install this package on RHEL/CentOS 7.9.